# Code is not working - Selenium 4.2.0 - I uninstalled and reinstalled Selenium and reinstalled Chrome Driver, there is no error message

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I had Selenium in an previous version, and installed Selenium 4.2.0, and my code is not working:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
servico = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
navegador = webdriver.Chrome(service=servico)
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time 
from selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException import NoSuchElementException

options = Options()
options.headless = False

navegador.get("https://receita.pr.gov.br/")
print ("Headless Chrome Initialized")

# entry with cpf
navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="cpfusuario"]').send_keys("000000000")
```

I uninstalled Selenium and reinstalled, also reinstalled Chrome Driver, but I don't know why it isn't working.

There is no error message.

Comment: Chrome and ChromeDriver versions please?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you initialized `options` after you already launched the driver. That should be done **before** you launch the driver so that you can use those `options` with any other argument that you want to pass in, such as the service:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Or in the case of your example with translation:

navegador = webdriver.Chrome(service=servico, options=options)
```

---